# Deleting rows older than rows in another table with same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, let's say X and Y, they have same structure.

X:

```
+----------+----+-------+
| date     | id | value |
+----------+----+-------+
| 1.1.2019 | 1  | 1     |
| 1.1.2019 | 2  | 1     |
| 1.3.2019 | 3  | 1     |
+----------+----+-------+
```

Y:

```
+----------+----+-------+
| date     | id | value |
+----------+----+-------+
| 1.2.2019 | 1  | 1     |
| 1.3.2019 | 2  | 1     |
+----------+----+-------+
```

I want to delete all rows from table X that have the same ids as in table Y but have older date, so desired output would look like so:

```
+----------+----+-------+
| date     | id | value |
+----------+----+-------+
| 1.3.2019 | 3  | 1     |
+----------+----+-------+
```

sadly none of my code works :/

Comment: older date compare to what?

Comment: @mkRabbani with date older than date in the rows with same id in the Y table

Comment: i assume those date columns are `VARCHAR|CHAR` datatypes?  You should be starting using `DATE` datetype and the date format `2019-01-01`

Comment: .. otherwise you would have to use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) all the time when comparing those strings as valid dates

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` in the `delete`:

```
delete x
    from x join
         y
         on x.id = y.id and x.date < y.date;
```

If you just want to select such rows (which is safer in my opinion):

```
select x.*
from x join
     y
     on x.id = y.id and x.date < y.date;
```

The above make the eminently sensible assumption that `date` is stored as a date/time format, not a string.

If your "date" column is stored as a string, you should fix the data.  First, convert the format into the default format on your system:

```
update x
    set x.date = str_to_date(x.date, <whatever the format is here>);
```

The date format is ambiguous -- I don't know which is the day and which is the month.

Then convert the column to a date:

```
alter table t
    modify column date date;
```

Comment: Not sure this is the correct approach if the date column is a CHAR or VARCHAR datatype which is looks like it is when looking into the example data. As `SELECT '1.2.2019' < '10.1.2019'` = `1`

Comment: @RaymondNijland It's still the correct approach though - even if the OP has to revise their data model to suit.

Comment: @Strawberry yes i more meant that the string compare is not safe to use without the topicstarter changing his data model

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join to filter out the table X and delete the row.

```
DELETE X
FROM x X
LEFT JOIN y Y ON X.id = Y.id
WHERE Y.id IS NOT NULL
    AND Y.DATE > X.DATE
```

Comment: Not sure this is the correct approach if the date column is a CHAR or VARCHAR datatype which is looks like it is when looking into the example data.  `As SELECT '1.2.2019' > '10.1.2019'` = `0`

Comment: @RaymondNijland-  You can use the convert over the date column in the where clause. Or you have to use the DateTime type.  I suggest you use the DateTime type.

Comment: *"You can use the convert over the date column in the where clause. "* yes i know your query is unsafe to use without using [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) that was mine point.. Consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/EEGuEUpkdfLsePdkYxqQJ/0) where the last gives the correct answer assuming the topicstarter used the format as `day.month.year`